# Creating Subfolders and directories on Jekyll

Tags: gitlab, jekyll

I currently have some documentation that is written with Markdown, that I want to transfer to a Jekyll type that will be built as part of my gitlab pipeline.

Currently, I have the following structure for my documentation.

```
-- docs
   -- schemas
      -- dbo.md
      -- raw.md
   -- Tables
      -- instances.md
   -- Views
      -- environments.md
```

I am struggling to find a documentation or an example like that. Usually, all the examples are talking about posts, which is just one level, and it is not helping me.

Appreciate any guidance.

Nothing to add in here.